# Influence of mass extinction on evolution

Tags: evolution

It is said that mass extinctions on earth occur somewhat periodically [(every 20 to 30 million years)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_event#Patterns_in_frequency).

There are two opposites way to look at how those may influence evolution:

- On the one hand it speeds up evolution, by freeing ecological niches that were previously occupied. One could also say that it helps genetic drift.
- On the other hand if mass extinctions happen too often then it is at risk of limiting life's diversity, by selecting species that are capable of withstanding such events (such as extremophiles), or even destroying life altogether.

In the case where mass extinctions would happen *more* frequently, how often could they happen and still allow for intelligent life to evolve?

In the case where there would be *no* mass extinctions, would intelligent life still evolve, or is it possible that life reaches a sort of equilibrium and never goes further?

A somewhat related question: [What if the asteroid never hit?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4812/what-if-the-asteroid-never-hit/4872#4872)

Comment: Do you have a reference for this or a more detailed explanation : It is said that mass extinctions on earth occur somewhat periodically (every 20 to 30 million years).

Comment: My only reference is wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_event#Patterns_in_frequency

Comment: I edited the question. Please tell me if it is still too broad.

Comment: @skysurf3000 There are *too many* questions. You should be able to pick out one or two that you want answered; the second one in your first section of questions seems a good fit here.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Thank you, I removed the ones that weren't about intelligent life.

Comment: @skysurf3000 Thanks. Voted to reopen

Comment: Much better now. I'm also voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

Darwin is often misquoted/oversimplified. Evolution isn't about "survival of the fittest", it is about the "survival of those who fit into an available ecological niche." More frequent mass extinctions shake things up more often, so evolution has a chance to work faster.

- Does that mean *better* species (smarter, tougher, ...) or simply more frequent adaptation to new niches?
- Once you get a sentient species, will evolution still matter? No matter how lethal a tiger is, it can't beat a rifle. You might get that sentient species earlier during the evolution of the planet.

Comment: I think evolution does matter on sentient species. To stick to your picture: One thing that beats a rifle is a better rifle.

Comment: @Burki Evolution would matter in that instance only if there were multiple sentient (or semi-sentient) species with guns. I think if you look at our history you would see that one of multiple sentient species will most likely adapt and conquer the world, leaving any others (like the Neanderthal) "in the dust" so to speak. It probably wouldn't make it to the gun stage before the fittest race came out on top.

Comment: @DustinJackson i agree with you there. I was thinking about the evolution of the dominant species. But i guess that will happen anyway, and it will happen outside of the scope of this topic.

Comment: @Burki We have been virtually unchanged for a very long time. I doubt evolution will ever naturally effect us. Not to say that we won't upgrade our own bodies :)

Comment: *Evolution* is the overall change of a species over time; *natural selection* is the oft-quoted "survival of the fittest".

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an idea generator, but it does point you in a solid direction. It got me studying saurian evolution.
If you look at body size and feature pattern, you notice that there are two co-evolving trends: larger bodies (for both predators and prey) among established clade, and the formation of small bodied clade that fill niches around these apex dwellers. 
For example: the first tyrannosuarid predators were of relatively modest size, but rapidly grew into their new niche, opening the spots they previously occupied for the raptor-type dinosaurs. This "market segmentation" meant that more body types became feasible, since a T Rex (or even a velociraptor) wouldn't bother eating a tiny Dino like compsignithus (definitely spelled that wrong...) So large predators wouldn't eat small prey and large prey species wouldn't need to worry about small predators.
As you increase in size, birth rate trends suggest you get smaller populations and a slower rate to maturation. Speciation would slow down in such individuals compared to microfauna.
I think the best hypothetical example are the "How to Train your Dragon" movies: a tiny number of HUGE alpha/apex predators, and a large number of smaller, more diverse species. 
It's unlikely humans would evolve in such a scenario - size and strength are better values than energetically costly intelligence.